# mysql2 gem crashes Rails on CentOS 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mysql2

I am using the mysql2 gem in my Rails code on a CentOS 6 system, and when Rails starts up, I see an error like this when Rails try to connect to the MySQL database :

```
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': 
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/mysql2-
0.3.17/mysql2/mysql2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE - 
/home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/mysql2-
0.3.17/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)

from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/mysql2-0.3.17/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.7.9/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
from /u/apps/api/releases/20141218200648/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /u/apps/api/releases/20141218200648/config/environment.rb:1:in `require'
from /u/apps/api/releases/20141218200648/config/environment.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from config.ru:4:in `require'
from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
from config.ru:1:in `new'
from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `call'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:760:in `call'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:760:in `build_app!'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:137:in `start'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/gems/unicorn-4.8.2/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@api/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone ever encountered something similar to this error before?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use a gem built against a different MySQL client library than the one you're trying to use. Even just compiled with different compilers they are different. Did you copy the gem from another machine or do anything else just as obvious to mismatch the libraries?

Comment: Hi D-side, no I did not copy it from another machine, I am just using the latest mysql2 gem version which is 0.3.17.  My machine is using MySQL 5.6.22, and the MySQL client library I have installed is MySQL-devel-5.6.22-1.el7.x86_64.rpm from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/  .    So, yea, the mysql2 gem might have issues with it? Is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: it just looks as if the gem's native extension was linked (on your machine, during build) with a different library version than is used in the system. I can say nothing more, this needs more information. Plus, I've not yet encountered issues like this before.